# Add custom htaccess record for custom url path rewrite within wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've integrated a custom PHP script within my wordpress instalation (with theme page-template). 
The page is `/islands/island/` and I get the islandId with GET paramater. So the URL looks like `https://website.com/islands/island/?iid=1`

But now I want to rewrite the url to be like this: `https://website.com/islands/island/1`

I already tried edditing the .htaccess but with no luck.

After some research I found editing .htaccess is not the right way to do this. So I used the followingn code and added it to my theme's function.php.

```
function add_directory_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%iid%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^islands/island/([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=islands/island&iid=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_directory_rewrite' );
```

But unfortunately it is not working. When I browse to the page `http://website.com/islands/island/1` it redirects to `http://website.com/islands/island/`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You should showcase some of the no luck editing. Else take a look at the linked tutorials first.

Comment: The duplicate you set is based on normal PHP websites, not Wordpress. I've added some of the code.

Comment: The proper placeholder would be `\d+`. Reopened, if you feel the unreliable WP dispatching is preferrable over a classic RewriteRule.

Comment: With integrating in plugins and themes you have to use WP function if you do not want to manually change htaccess for each install right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!
Working code:

```
function add_directory_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%iid%", '[\d+]');
    add_rewrite_rule('islands/island/([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=islands/island&iid=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_directory_rewrite' );
```

Changed the placeholder tags as @Mario suggested.